# How to implement an Eclipse IDE extension to listen to MANIFEST.MF changes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to have a functionality on my Eclipse IDE to validate the consistency of the dependencies defined on a plugin manifest. That would mean that each time a MANIFEST.MF file is modified (i.e. by adding a new plugin dependency) some code is triggered in order to check whether new added dependencies are valid and warn the developer in case the dependencies are not valid.

Which are the key points I would have to research? Does Eclipse provide extension points to listen to save/build processes? Where can I find a list of possible extension points I can contribute to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen to all resource changes or maybe add an incremental builder to the project which will be called during builds.

Comment: I can't really help with the actual question but I would consider other approaches before writing a plugin. For example you could write test that checks the dependencies. That would make it easier if you need to change the behavior (which is likely project specific anyway). I had good success with ArchUnit for checking for invalid dependencies. It doesn't support Manifest dependencies though, it analyzes actual usage of types but it still works well enough for plugin projects.

Comment: @kapex Thanks for the contribution. I didn't thought about that possibility but sounds also interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @greg-449 mentioned you can use [org.eclipse.core.resources.builders](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_core_resources_builders.html) 
and also implement [IModelChangedListener](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/api/org/eclipse/pde/core/IModelChangedListener.html) that should guide you to the subject more directly.